# php блок с кодом в комментариях

Tags: php, javascript

Вот как на этом сайте в вопросе я могу написать комментарий и пример кода, например:

Это комментарий

```
//это код
<script>alert('1');</script>
```

Это еще комментарий

Как правильно такое реализовывается, что бы комментарий был защищен от XSS, а код в комментарии отображался как код!
Как сохраняется такой коммент в базу, пример кода извлекается и хранится отдельно? или коммент сохраняется как единое целое?
Как отображать (обрабатывать при отображении) такой комментарий?

Может кто-то написать пример, или дать ссылку на какой-то пример или ссылку на скрипт где такое реализовано, не могу найти!

Comment: еммм, как минумум XSS узвимость связана с js, а не php

Comment: @darkwoolf причем тут это? я написал php так как хочу узнать как это делается на php... коммент от бога! Неужели вопрос не ясен =)

Comment: Ага, а при сохранении в базу можно напороться ещё и на другой тип уязвимостей -- SQL Injection.

Comment: @AK да? что серьезно? Я вроде не спрашивал, на что можно напороться

Comment: @user3737786 Вы не обижайтесь, но вопрос реально достаточно большой, с многим числом ньюансов. Вам вообще важно самому написать свой собственный код (тут масса вопросов - работа с mysql в php и так далее) или вообще хотите красивую подсветку синтаксиса разных языков (есть куча готовых решения, не нужно велосипеды делать).

Comment: @AK подсветка синтаксиса не нужна, если есть куча готовых решений то дайте ссылку на такое решение!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! я в вопросе просил ссылку!

Comment: Мой бог... Стыдно слышать такое от человека с репой более 300. Вас в гугле забанили? Вбейте "скрипты для подсветки синтаксиса" и подберите то, которое подходит под ваши нужнды более оптимальным образом. Предлагаю закрыть.вопрос как неконкретный, общий и неконструктивный.

Comment: @AK мне подсветка синтаксиса не нужна, стыдно слышать

Comment: Извините, но ваш вопрос "не отражает стремления разобраться" (С)

Comment: @AK мне подсветка синтаксиса не нужна, я хочу узнать как такие комментарии обрабатываются на php (сохраняются в базу и выводятся), что бы комментарий был защищен от XSS, а код в комментарии отображался как пример кода(как код, как на этом сайте), а вы мне все подсветку синтаксиса тычите

Answer (score 6):

В вашем вопросе много разных вопросов.

1. Комментарии в базу сохраняются типовым способом. Есть допустим, mysql-база, в ней, допустим таблица постов (is, author, date, comment, id_parent). Вам нужно сохранить пришедшие из html-формы данные в базу, для защиты от sql injection есть два типовых способа. Тут уже масса вопросов, это я только группу обозначил. Вряд ли вы задумываетесь например о версионировании структуры таблицы (phinx) и многом прочем.
2. При выводе сообщения нужно прочитать из базы нужный пост(ы), при этом если вы хотите организовать "посветку кода", то в минимальном случае вы должны искать код в теле поста и обрамлять его в стилизованные тэги `<pre>` и `</pre>` ну там border, фон... Самое простое -- вы договариваетесь, что начало кода будет оформлено при помощи `[CODE]`, а конец - при помощи `[/CODE]`. Почему именно квадратные скобки, а не треугольные -- так вы избежите проблем с html (не спутать при парсинге - раз, защита от xss - два). Более продвинутые парсеры умеют markdown-разметку (как на so), но вам туда самостоятельно лучше не колхозить велосипеды -- соберёте все грабли и уязвимости.

Достаточно? Мини-лекция получается, чисто вводный курс.

PS Конкретизируйте ваши вопросы!

Comment: 2 раза писал, подсветка синтаксиса не нужна, но так и дошло, все равно пишет про подсветку синтаксиса. Далее пишет "более продвинутые парсеры" - дай ты уже хоть 1 ссылку на такой парсер

Comment: @user3737786, [ТУЦ](http://stackapps.com/questions/4435/ace-overflow-google-chrome-extension-that-replaces-wmd-editor-with-ace-on-all), а там и ссылки на github

Comment: Тэги которые я вам приводил в пример называются BBCODE, это очень широко распространённая в сети вещь. Гуглите любой готовый парсер BBCODE - вот [тут например](https://toster.ru/q/305) и велосипед есть и мощное готовое решение.. Но это только малая часть  того, что вам нужно -- у вас тут вопросов ещё вагон и малая тележка, изучать и изучать программирование.

Comment: Неконструктив и неадекват. До свидания, ищите кого другого, кто вас будет просвещать... если захочет связываться.

Comment: @Doofy ну наконец-то я понял, все это делается на уровне JS, а потом просто вставляется в базу... ппц, спасибо.

Comment: @AK отправил участнику небольшую памятку, может быть образумится.